# boost.log как правильно собрать и использовать

Tags: boost

Пользовался библиотекой boost много раз разными версиями, и вот возникла задача поддержать старый код на C++ 2003, для начала нужно было приделать лог и решил взять лог из библиотеки `boost`. Закачал версию 1.70 и начал сборку:

```
1) D:\libs\boost_1_70_0>bootstrap.bat
2) D:\libs\boost_1_70_0>b2 toolset=msvc variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static address-model=32 -j4 --stagedir=D:\libs\boost_1_70_0\vs2008\Win32\static
```

Все собралось boost пишет:

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
    D:\libs\boost_1_70_0
The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
    D:\libs\boost_1_70_0\vs2008\Win32\static\lib
```

Делаю тестовый проект с логом, указываю:

```
1) Additional Include Directories: D:\libs\boost_1_70_0
2) Additional Library Directories: D:\libs\boost_1_70_0\vs2008\Win32\static\lib
```

Собираю и получаю вот такое интересное сообщение:

```
1>Compiling...
1>boost_logger.cpp
1>d:\libs\boost_1_70_0\boost\config\auto_link.hpp(396) : fatal error C1189: #error :  "Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea..."
1>simplelogger.cpp
1>d:\libs\boost_1_70_0\boost\config\auto_link.hpp(396) : fatal error C1189: #error :  "Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea..."
```

Уже пару дней не могу это победить подскажите кто знает, другое пробовал из библиотеки типа `boost::shared_ptr, boost::filesystem` работает, с boost.log какие-то грабли кто знает подскажите в чем дело?

Comment: вы для чего собрали с `runtime-link=static`?

Answer (score 0):

В куске кода который я скопипастил себе в проект из примеров был замечательный макрос

```
#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
```

который вставлял палки в колеса... жесть столько времени...